# Как извлечь сумму покупки из заданной строки?

Tags: java, android, регулярные-выражения

**Дано:** VISA7777 27.09.17 19:46 pokupka 962.23RUB PYATEROCHKA 3344 Баланс: 443272.29RUB

**Нужно:** 962.23

Comment: Сами хоть пытались?

Comment: если сам сделал бы вопрос не задал) 962 получаю а дробную часть нет, хочется сделать регулярками, а с ними не знаком

Comment: Регулярные выражения в данном случае - стрельба из пушки по воробьям. Достаточно метода indexOf() для поиска "RUB" и некоторого отсчёта назад (например, поиска пробела слева).

Comment: @CoolMind, я знаю я так и сделал сперва, потом захотел регуляркой)

Comment: Клёвый вы себе ник взяли. Я думаю, производительность регулярки ниже, хотя код - проще.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Берете первое совпадение по паттерну:

```
([0-9.]*)(?=RUB)
```

Что-то вроде:

```
  String sourcestring = "VISA7777 27.09.17 19:46 pokupka 962.23RUB PYATEROCHKA 3344 Баланс: 443272.29RUB";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("([0-9.]*)(?=RUB)");
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  m.find();
  System.out.println(m.group(0));
```

[Тестить](http://ideone.com/aHhBuA)!

Comment: спасибо, знал что регулярками это быстро)))

Comment: @java добавил пример и ссылку на фиддл

Comment: спасибо большое!!